# Autoplay audacious running multiple times

Tags: 14.04, audacious, autoplay

In the cd autoplay, I run this command:

```
audacious -q -p -h cdda://
```

But then after inserting a cd, audacious is started three times! And the sound becomes a lot of noise then. Running Ubuntu 14.04 with XFCE. See attached screenprints of removable media settings and the system monitor after autoplay has started.

Hope someone can help me with this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your commandline:

```
audacious -q -p -h cdda://
```

is *incorrect* as the `-h` option you give is this one:

```
-h, --help
      Show a brief list of options.
```

I suspect you are actually after the `-H` option:

```
-H, --headless
      Start in command-line mode; i.e., without any graphical user interface.
```

This then is the commandline you need:

```
audacious -q -p -H cdda://
```

Comment: @Stuiter  Great news!! If the answer has worked for you could you 'Accept' it by clicking on the tick mark or check mark  next to my answer. And have a good day :)